# Adding hyperlinks to Leaflet polylines created via Leaflet.Draw?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, web-mapping, line

[Cross posting from StackOverflow as I realized this may be a more specific community for this]

I'm using Leaflet.Draw, and I want to allow the lines that I draw to have hyperlinks in them so that someone can click on the link and open a new page.

How do I add a link to a polyline created via Leaflet.Draw? When I addLayer to drawnItems, how can I give that layer another attribute that could be a URL?

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
mapLink = 
    '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
L.tileLayer(
    'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
    maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);

var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

Comment: You can include hyperlinks in the text popup, is that what you mean -- or do you want the line feature itself to be a link?

Comment: This was cross-posted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357814/how-do-you-add-hyperlinks-to-leaflet-polylines-created-via-leaflet-draw  If you decide that you have tried the "wrong" SE/SO site first then you may not be aware that there is an option to flag the moderators and request that it be migrated rather than creating cross-posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will open a new page when the drawn feature is clicked:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    layer.on('click', function(){
        window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank');
    });  

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

This will bind a popup with a url:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    layer.bindPopup('<a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>');

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

But not sure what you are after here exactly; you may want to add more information to the question. In general, the 'draw:created' callback is the place where you would add this functionality.